# TYPO3 Static template not being included in Template hierarchy?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a site package that I need to include in Static Templates.

It has been added as the last template under `Includes` > `Selected Items`, but if I then go to the `Template Analyzer` it is not listed.

In another offline installation of TYPO3 I use to test on, the static template is added and working perfectly. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Maybe some caching, so in the one instance, TS is still in an outdated version while the other instance is showing the current state of TS? Or maybe an issue with case-sensitive filesystem and path to the TS file?

Comment: @JulianHofmann I added 2 different sitepackages today and only one has this problem. There isn't much difference between them in setup, so if it were a cache or case thing I would expect they both would have the problem?

Comment: I would expect the same. So it must be the difference of the instances or the sitepackages, which causes this problem.

Comment: @JulianHofmann I created another bare bones 'hello world' site package with only `ext_emconf.php`, `setup.typoscript`, and `sys_template.php` and the same problem occurs. I can add it under includes, but it won't list it under Teamplate analyzer > template hierarchy.

Comment: @JulianHofmann You were right, it was a case thing! I accidentally named the folder `Typoscript` instead of `TypoScript`. How frustrating...

Comment: Don't be frustrated. Often it's such simple things... Especially with "strange" behavior, it is a good approach to take a close look at the basics. Yes, it's annoying at times (and my co-workers hate me for it), but often the flaws are in those very details.

Comment: Would you please write a short answer to your question so it can be marked as solved? Thanks.

Comment: @JulianHofmann Since you had the answer in your first comment, you should add it and I will mark it as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Includes` > `Selected Items` you are registering a label-value-pair for the select field only. To be shown, it is only necessary that your extension is installed/active. The content of this registration is not checked.

In contrast to this, the specified file is read during parsing. I.e. errors in the pathname take effect here. So here it is crucial that the registered path matches the actual path of the file - if necessary, including the consideration of the upper and lower case (or camelCase).